# How to get debug video data playbackQuality from youtube?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

Each youtube video has the ability to get debug data by right-clicking and selecting the desired item in the "**Copy data for debugging**" menu

The value of the **debug_playbackQuality** field is important to me

How can I get this data using youtube api or some other way? Or how to get the **debug_playbackQuality** value right away?

Heard about the [player.getPlaybackQuality (): String](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es-419#Playback_quality) function but it looks like it works with js, I need php

When working with the youtube api, I need to get the value of the debug_playbackQuality parameter for each video (similar to privacyStatus and embeddable) and then, based on the data, make a decision about further work with the video. I don't know how to check the value of debug_playbackQuality.

Help me figure it out, please.

[image]

p.s.

**Try to run this video** https://www.youtube.com/embed/1fO1HmgBHaE

Oops!

These videos are check for privacyStatus and embeddable!

privacyStatus = public, embeddable = true

Because of this, videos are embedded in the site, but do not work on it.

I found the difference - solution!

These videos have a status equal to "debug_playbackQuality": "**unknown**"!

[image]

**The only option not to add them to the site is to check the debug_playbackQuality by unknown status!**